# \endlastfoot text is a single line that exceeds table boundaries when using \multicolumn in \longtable environment

Tags: longtable, multicolumn

I need a longtable with 2 lines of description in the `\endlastfoot` that do not exceed the column width. Picture 1 is my table as I want it but with the `\endlastfoot` text squeezed into 1 column. Picture 2 is a single line of text after using `\multicolumn{5}{l}` before `\textit{Note.}` ...

How can I get the text in `\endlastfoot` to be as wide as the table in Picture 1 and still break the line?

[image: Desired longtable but with \endlastfoot all in 1 column]

[image: Longtable with multicolumn for \endlastfoot exceeds table boundaries]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{apacite}
    \bibliographystyle{apacite}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, bottom=3cm,top=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{setspace}
    \doublespacing


\usepackage{multirow,booktabs,setspace,caption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator*{spaced}{\\[2ex]}
\captionsetup[table]{textfont=it,format=plain,justification=justified,
  singlelinecheck=false,labelsep=newline,skip=0pt}

\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\section{A}

\begin{singlespacing}

\begin{longtable}{p{0.02\textwidth}p{0.08\textwidth}p{0.12\textwidth}p{0.115\textwidth}p{0.6\textwidth}}
\caption{53 op kop kop kop kopkop kop }\\
\toprule
Nr. & PANAS* & Temporality & Content** & Topic \\
\hline
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{5}{l}%
{\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\
\hline
\toprule
Nr. & PANAS* & Temporality & Content** & Topic \\
\hline
\endhead
\hline \multicolumn{5}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
\endfoot
\hline

\textit{Note.} *See Table 2 on the PANAS-SF version that was used in this case-study. ***See Table 3 on how the content of thought was assessed. 
\endlastfoot


1 & +33 -11 (+19) & kop & kop 4 & kop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kop\\
[1.5cm]
1 & +33 -11 (+19) & kop & kop 4 & kop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kop\\
[1.5cm]
1 & +33 -11 (+19) & kop & kop 4 & kop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kop\\
[1.5cm]
1 & +33 -11 (+19) & kop & kop 4 & kop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kop\\
[1.5cm]
1 & +33 -11 (+19) & kop & kop 4 & kop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kop\\
[1.5cm]
1 & +33 -11 (+19) & kop & kop 4 & kop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kop\\
[1.5cm]
1 & +33 -11 (+19) & kop & kop 4 & kop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kop\\
[1.5cm]
1 & +33 -11 (+19) & kop & kop 4 & kop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kop\\
[1.5cm]

\end{longtable}

\end{singlespacing}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Either use a p type column of appropriate width for the multicolumn command or take a look at the threeparttablex package.

Comment: Could you give me an example of how to use p type column for multicolumn command? I already used p type columns to set the number and width of each columns, but can't just copy paste that line into the multicolumn {here} {l} Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
....
\hline \\
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\multirow{1}{\textwidth}{\textit{Notes.} \\  \textsuperscript{*}See Table 2 on the PANAS-SF version that was used in this case-study.\\ \textsuperscript{**}See Table 3 on how the content of thought was assessed. }}
\endlastfoot
```

[image: x3]

Or

```
\hline \\
\parbox{\textwidth}{\textit{Notes.} \\  \textsuperscript{*}See Table 2 on the PANAS-SF version that was used in this case-study.\\ \textsuperscript{**}See Table 3 on how the content of thought was assessed. }    
\endlastfoot
```

This is the output with `\usepackage{mathptmx}` commented. See the italics coming back.

[image]

Since you already are using `booktabs` try this

```
\begin{longtable}{p{0.02\textwidth}p{0.08\textwidth}p{0.12\textwidth}p{0.115\textwidth}p{0.6\textwidth}}
    \caption{53 op kop kop kop kopkop kop }\\
    \toprule
    Nr. & PANAS* & Temporality & Content** & Topic \\
    \midrule
\endfirsthead
    \multicolumn{5}{l}%
    {\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\
    \midrule
    Nr. & PANAS* & Temporality & Content** & Topic \\
    \midrule
\endhead
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{5}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
    \endfoot
    \midrule
    \parbox{\textwidth}{\textit{Notes.} \\  \textsuperscript{*}See Table 2 on the PANAS-SF version that was used in this case-study.\\ \textsuperscript{**}See Table 3 on how the content of thought was assessed. }    
\endlastfoot
```

Comment: You the real MVP. The bottom one did the better job for me as I was working with rather narrow vertical spacing.

Comment: Thank you. I made another suggestion to allow some vertical space between the line and Continued on .. and better with Notes.

Answer (score 0):

With `xltabular` instead of `longtable` in order to make sure the table fits into the available textwidth and a `p` type column of appropriate width in the `\multicolumn` command:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{apacite}
    \bibliographystyle{apacite}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, bottom=3cm,top=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{setspace}
    \doublespacing

\usepackage{multirow,booktabs,setspace,caption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator*{spaced}{\\[2ex]}
\captionsetup[table]{textfont=it,format=plain,justification=justified,
  singlelinecheck=false,labelsep=newline,skip=0pt}

\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{calc}
\begin{document}

\section{A}

\begin{singlespacing}

\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{l
                  p{\widthof{PANAS*}}
                  l
                  l
                  X}
\caption{53 op kop kop kop kopkop kop }\\
\toprule
Nr. & PANAS* & Temporality & Content** & Topic \\
\hline
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{5}{l}%
{\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\
\hline
\toprule
Nr. & PANAS* & Temporality & Content** & Topic \\
\hline
\endhead
\hline \multicolumn{5}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
\endfoot
\hline

\multicolumn{5}{p{\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}}{\textit{Note.} *See Table 2 on the PANAS-SF version that was used in this case-study. ***See Table 3 on how the content of thought was assessed.}
\endlastfoot


1 & +33 -11 (+19) & kop & kop 4 & kop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kop\\
\addlinespace
1 & +33 -11 (+19) & kop & kop 4 & kop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kop\\
\addlinespace
1 & +33 -11 (+19) & kop & kop 4 & kop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kop\\
\addlinespace
1 & +33 -11 (+19) & kop & kop 4 & kop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kop\\
\addlinespace
1 & +33 -11 (+19) & kop & kop 4 & kop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kop\\
\addlinespace
1 & +33 -11 (+19) & kop & kop 4 & kop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kop\\
[1.5cm]
1 & +33 -11 (+19) & kop & kop 4 & kop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kop\\
\addlinespace
1 & +33 -11 (+19) & kop & kop 4 & kop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kop\\
\addlinespace
1 & +33 -11 (+19) & kop & kop 4 & kop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kop\\
[1.5cm]
1 & +33 -11 (+19) & kop & kop 4 & kop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kop\\
\addlinespace
1 & +33 -11 (+19) & kop & kop 4 & kop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kopkop kop kop kop kop kop\\
\addlinespace
\end{xltabular}

\end{singlespacing}

\end{document}
```